# When do we call the inner function in the de-facto decorator?

Tags: python, decorator

I'm struggling to understand comparators in Python and one of the tutorials suggests looking at the following example:

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapper():
        print("Something is happening before the function is called.")
        func()
        print("Something is happening after the function is called.")
    return wrapper

def say_whee():
    print("Whee!")

say_whee = my_decorator(say_whee)

say_whee()
```

When I call `say_whee()` it prints the following:

```
Something is happening before the function is called.
Whee!
Something is happening after the function is called.
```

I vaguely understand why it prints these lines but I don't understand when exactly we call `wrapper()` so it could print these lines.

At what moment do we call `wrapper()`?

Comment: After applying the decorator, `say_whee` *is* the wrapper (instead of the original function, which now only the wrapper has a reference to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *return `wrapper`* and assign it to `say_wee`:

```
say_whee = my_decorator(say_whee)
```

So it is called here:

```
say_whee()
```

See for yourself:

```
>>> def my_decorator(func):
...     def wrapper():
...         print("Something is happening before the function is called.")
...         func()
...         print("Something is happening after the function is called.")
...     return wrapper
...
>>> def say_whee():
...     print("Whee!")
...
>>> say_whee = my_decorator(say_whee)
>>>
>>> say_whee
<function my_decorator.<locals>.wrapper at 0x1040d89d8>
>>> say_whee.__name__
'wrapper'
```

Comment: Very well said. `wrapper` is what was called the moment you do `say_whee()` because at `say_whee = my_decorator(say_whee)`,  `say_whee` gets overwritten by what is returned by `my_decorator(say_whee)`; and that is wrapper.